# log shipping restore job

Tags: sql-server, ssms

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: This backup cannot be restored using WITH STANDBY because a database upgrade is needed. Reissue the RESTORE without WITH STANDBY. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Answer (score 3):

You are shipping to a higher version of SQL Server. You can't do that with standby/readonly mode. You have to use the norecovery option instead.